# Java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0 Android

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have been getting this error for DAYS maybe a week and I still can't fix it and no one can help me .

I am using a Instagram clone app to create an app like Instagram . I have these errors I have been getting and I can't fix it and no one on here seems to be able to either .

```
07-09 11:48:43.307 19532-19532/tabian.com.hash E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: tabian.com.hash, PID: 19532
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
at tabian.com.hash.Share.GalleryFragment.setupGridView(GalleryFragment.java:159)
at tabian.com.hash.Share.GalleryFragment.access$300(GalleryFragment.java:38)
at tabian.com.hash.Share.GalleryFragment$3.onItemSelected(GalleryFragment.java:134)
```

The file has no errors or even warnings or typos . I only get this when I try to access my camera in my phone . I tried changing code, moving code and adding code and nothing worked . I tried reducing the `targetSdkVersion` and the `minSdkVersion` and I still get the error .

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {
private static final String TAG = "GalleryFragment";

//constants
private static final int NUM_GRID_COLUMNS = 3;

//widgets
private GridView gridView;
private ImageView galleryImage;
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
private Spinner directorySpinner;

//vars
private ArrayList<String> directories;
private String mAppend = "file:/";
private String mSelectedImage;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
    galleryImage = view.findViewById(R.id.galleryImageView);
    gridView = view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    directorySpinner = view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerDirectory);
    mProgressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    directories = new ArrayList<>();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: started.");

    ImageView shareClose = view.findViewById(R.id.ivCloseShare);
    shareClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: closing the gallery fragment.");
            Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).finish();
        }
    });

    TextView nextScreen = view.findViewById(R.id.tvNext);
    nextScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: navigating to the final share screen.");

            if(isRootTask()){
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NextActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.selected_image), mSelectedImage);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else{
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AccountSettingsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.selected_image), mSelectedImage);
                intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.return_to_fragment), getString(R.string.edit_profile_fragment));
                startActivity(intent);
                Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).finish();
            }

        }
    });

    init();

    return view;
}

private boolean isRootTask(){
    return ((ShareActivity) Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).getTask() == 0;
}

private void init(){
    FilePaths filePaths = new FilePaths();

    //check for other folders inside "/storage/emulated/0/pictures"
    if (FileSearch.getDirectoryPaths(filePaths.PICTURES) != null) {
        directories = FileSearch.getDirectoryPaths(filePaths.PICTURES);
    }
    directories.add(filePaths.CAMERA);

    ArrayList<String> directoryNames = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < directories.size(); i++) {
        Log.d(TAG, "init: directory: " + directories.get(i));
        int index = directories.get(i).lastIndexOf("/");
        String string = directories.get(i).substring(index);
        directoryNames.add(string);
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, directoryNames);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    directorySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    directorySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: selected: " + directories.get(position));

            //setup our image grid for the directory chosen
            setupGridView(directories.get(position));
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}

private void setupGridView(String selectedDirectory){
    Log.d(TAG, "setupGridView: directory chosen: " + selectedDirectory);
    final ArrayList<String> imgURLs = FileSearch.getFilePaths(selectedDirectory);

    //set the grid column width
    int gridWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    int imageWidth = gridWidth/NUM_GRID_COLUMNS;
    gridView.setColumnWidth(imageWidth);

    //use the grid adapter to adapter the images to gridview
    GridImageAdapter adapter = new GridImageAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.layout_grid_imageview, mAppend, imgURLs);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //set the first image to be displayed when the activity fragment view is inflated
    try{
        setImage(imgURLs.get(0), galleryImage, mAppend);
        mSelectedImage = imgURLs.get(0);
    }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "setupGridView: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: " +e.getMessage() );
    }

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: selected an image: " + imgURLs.get(position));

            setImage(imgURLs.get(position), galleryImage, mAppend);
            mSelectedImage = imgURLs.get(position);
        }
    });

}

private void setImage(String imgURL, ImageView image, String append){
    Log.d(TAG, "setImage: setting image");

    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

    imageLoader.displayImage(append + imgURL, image, new ImageLoadingListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Can someone please help me . This is very important to me .

EDITTT !!

```
   private void setupGridView(String selectedDirectory){
    Log.d(TAG, "setupGridView: directory chosen: " + selectedDirectory);
    final ArrayList<String> imgURLs = 
FileSearch.getFilePaths(selectedDirectory);

    //set the grid column width
    int gridWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    int imageWidth = gridWidth/NUM_GRID_COLUMNS;
    gridView.setColumnWidth(imageWidth);

    //use the grid adapter to adapter the images to gridview
    GridImageAdapter adapter = new GridImageAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.layout_grid_imageview, mAppend, imgURLs);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    if (imgURLs.isEmpty()) {
        // Array list is empty, handle accordingly
    } else {
        //set the first image to be displayed when the activity fragment view is inflated
        try {
            setImage(imgURLs.get(0), galleryImage, mAppend);
            mSelectedImage = imgURLs.get(0);
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "setupGridView: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: selected an image: " + imgURLs.get(position));

                setImage(imgURLs.get(position), galleryImage, mAppend);
                mSelectedImage = imgURLs.get(position);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[The errors I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXMKr.png)

Comment: Check `imgURLs.size()`. It's probably empty.

Comment: You could google it a little, maybe. This is a very common question.

Comment: @MichaelDodd this is how it looks `setImage(imgURLs.get(0), galleryImage, mAppend);`

Comment: @luiscosta that is literally ALL I have been doing and no answer has helped me .

Comment: That's why I said check the `size()` of `imgURLs`. If it's 0, then that's your problem.

Comment: I went through all of the topics I could find out there and nothing helped

Comment: I tried putting `1,2 and -1` and I still get the same error

Comment: @Newindie That's because your `ArrayList` **is empty**. You are trying to access an index that **does not exist**. You need to check that your `ArrayList` contains at least 1 item, and handle the error if it does not. [Documentation for `IndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html)

Comment: @MichaelDodd . I click one of the other errors and this is what I saw in the ArrayList.Java file

Comment: `* @param minCapacity the desired minimum capacity
     */
    private void grow(int minCapacity) {
        // overflow-conscious code
        int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
        int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);
        if (newCapacity - minCapacity < 0)
            newCapacity = minCapacity;
        if (newCapacity - MAX_ARRAY_SIZE > 0)
            newCapacity = hugeCapacity(minCapacity);
        // minCapacity is usually close to size, so this is a win:
        elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
    }`

Comment: It's supposed to open my gallery in my phone

Comment: @Newindie Can you add that code as an [edit to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51249745/edit)? It's not very readable as a comment.

Comment: @MichaelDodd I think that's just a partial dump of Java's `ArrayList` source code

Comment: @00 You're right, it's from `Arrays.java`. Absolutely no bearing on the question at all.

Comment: @MichaelDodd so you don't want to see the error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
final ArrayList<String> imgURLs = FileSearch.getFilePaths(selectedDirectory);
```

is returning an empty `ArrayList`, i.e. no file paths were returned. Because you are not checking for `imgURLs.isEmpty()`, you are attempting to `get()` index 0 of that `imgURLs`, which does not exist. Because of this, an [`IndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) is thrown.

You can avoid this crash by checking if `imgURLs` contains at least one item before continuing. For example:

```
private void setupGridView(String selectedDirectory){
    Log.d(TAG, "setupGridView: directory chosen: " + selectedDirectory);
    final ArrayList<String> imgURLs = FileSearch.getFilePaths(selectedDirectory);

    ...

    if (imgURLs.isEmpty()) {
        // Array list is empty, handle accordingly
    } else {
       //set the first image to be displayed when the activity fragment view is inflated
       try{
            setImage(imgURLs.get(0), galleryImage, mAppend);
            mSelectedImage = imgURLs.get(0);
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
             Log.e(TAG, "setupGridView: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: " +e.getMessage() );
        }
     }

     ...
 }
```

Comment: I just tried this code and I am still getting the same error

Comment: Can you update your code [as an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51249745/edit) to show how you implemented it? And do you still get exactly the same error?

Comment: Also note I'm catching `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, not `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: Yes I get the exact same errors . I'll post a picture of the errors I see

Comment: Please post your **full, updated** `setupGridView` method. You shouldn't be getting that error in exactly the same place if it's been implemented properly.

Comment: Yeah there's no way you should be getting that error on exactly the same line as before. Uninstall your app from your device, do a clean & build on the code, and re-install on your device.